# Swift. Thread corriendo incluso estando en otras apps

Tags: swift, hilos

Necesito mantener un thread funcionando incluso cuando el usuario está dentro de otra aplicación. He probado con el siguiente thread que funciona solo si mantengo la aplicación visible, una vez que apreto el home button, el thread queda pausado.

```
func prepareSync() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos .background).async {
        self.sync()
        sleep(5)
        self.prepareSync()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente no es posible, solo hay ciertos tipos de tareas que podes ejecutar en el background, como por ejemplo reproducción de musica o descarga asincronica de datos pero por un corto periodo de tiempo. Mas info en la web oficial de developers de Apple: [Background execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)